# Using Xpath to get an string from a webpage

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests

I am trying to get the uniprot ID from this webpage: [ENSEMBL](http://www.ensembl.org/id/ENST00000378404) . But I am having trouble using xpath. Right now I am getting an empty list and I do not understand why.

My idea is to write a small function that takes the ENSEMBL IDs and returns the uniprot ID.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
ens_code = 'ENST00000378404'
webpage = 'http://www.ensembl.org/id/'+ens_code

response = requests.get(webpage)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

path = '//*[@id="ensembl_panel_1"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/p/a'

uniprot_id = tree.xpath(path)

print uniprot_id
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

It is only printing the existing lists but is still returning the Nonetype list.

```
def getUniprot(ensembl_code):

    ensembl_code = ensembl_code[:-1]
    webpage = 'http://www.ensembl.org/id/'+ensembl_code
    response = requests.get(webpage)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
    path = '//div[@class="lhs" and text()="Uniprot"]/following-sibling::div/p/a/text()'

    uniprot_id = tree.xpath(path)
    if uniprot_id:
        print uniprot_id
        return uniprot_id
```

Comment: It is returning None as that is what your function is returning when you get no match

Comment: But how does it get by the if statement? What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: You should be checking the return value, just `return  tree.xpath(path)` and forget the if, then check outside the function,`ret =  getUniprot("whatever")` then `if ret` use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you *getting an empty list* is because it looks like you used the *xpath* that chrome supplied when you right clicked and chose *copy xpath*, the reason your xpath returns nothing is because the tag is not in the source, it is dynamically generated so what requests returns does not contain the element.

```
In [6]: response = requests.get(webpage)

In [7]: "ensembl_panel_1" in response.content
Out[7]: False
```

You should always check  the page source to see what you are actually getting back, what you see in the developer console is not necessarily what you get when you download the source.

You can also use a specific xpath in case there were other `http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/` on the page,  searching the  divs for a class with `"lhs"` and the text `Uniprot` then get the text from the first following anchor tag:

```
 path = '//div[@class="lhs" and text()="Uniprot"]/following::a[1]/text()'
```

Which would give you:

```
['Q8TDY3']
```

You can also select the following sibling div where the anchor is inside it's child p tag:

```
path =  '//div[@class="lhs" and text()="Uniprot"]/following-sibling::div/p/a/text()'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have another question. I have a problem as one if my IDs leads to a webpage but this one does not have this path as there is no UniprotID. How can I add an exception to avoid unexisting paths? Otherwise it's returning an empty list. To clarify: adding exceptions after the empty list doesnt allow me to get rid of it, no matter what. I have tried checking lenght and NoneType.

Comment: No prob, if there is no matching element, just check what the xpath returns, `if uniprot_id:` that will only be True if you find a match. Are you doing this in a loop?

Comment: just do the lookup once `uniprot_id =  tree.xpath(path)` then `if uniprot_id`